# create .xlsx file and save it in a location via save as dialog with tkinter for example -python3

Tags: python, tkinter, xlsxwriter

I´m relative new in programming and im facing a issue i cant solve after hours of searching and trying..

So what i would like to is.. i have a program which does do some measurement stuff.
What i want to do is to export these results into a excel file (.xlsx)

Creating the excel file is not a big problem with the xlswriter module.
If i don't choose a path for the .xlsx file it actually saves it in the directory where my scripts are. And if i want to choose a path i can add that very easily in my skript.

But now i want that the User that does do the meaurements can actually choose where the .xlsx file will be saved. This should be archived with the tkinter module i guess (im open for different solutions). So with the tkinter module i can open a Dialog where the User can choose the directory without editing/modifying the actual skript, which makes it User-frendly.

So i already have coded some lines which is actually close to work i think.
In the first part of my skript it creates a workbook and writes some stuff inside and closes it.
In the second part the Dialog to save the file will show up and i can choose the location where my .xlsx file will be saved.
But the Problem is, that the Dialog actually dont save the .xlsx file that was created in the first part.
It only saves a new .xlsx file which is empty and i cant even open.

So there must be a way.. where the tkinter Dialaog actually grabs the .xlsx file from the first part of my skript or from the actual workbook i created and put that into the tkinter Dialog so i can save the .xlsx file where the User wants to.

Does someone have any idea or can help me?

Oh and if you have any tipps regarding writing a question here it also appreciated, thanks! :)

skript:

```
#Import necessary Library                                                                                                                                                                  
import xlsxwriter                                                                                                                                                                          
from tkinter import *                                                                                                                                                                      
from tkinter import filedialog                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                           
savelocation = r'\Path'                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Create a workbook and add a worksheet.                                                                                                                                                   
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook (saveloaction)                                                                                                                                              
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Some data we want to write to the worksheet.                                                                                                                                             
expenses = (                                                                                                                                                                               
    ['Rent', 1000],                                                                                                                                                                        
    ['Gas',   100],                                                                                                                                                                        
    ['Food',  300],                                                                                                                                                                        
    ['Gym',    50],                                                                                                                                                                        
)                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.                                                                                                                            
row = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
col = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.                                                                                                                                       
for item, cost in (expenses):                                                                                                                                                              
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)                                                                                                                                                    
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)                                                                                                                                                    
    row += 1                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Write a total using a formula.                                                                                                                                                           
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')                                                                                                                                                           
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                           
workbook.close()                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#open file.                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#win = Tk()                                                                                                                                                                                
#win.withdraw()                                                                                                                                                                            
#openfile = filedialog.askopenfile(initialfile='Results.xlsx', initialdir=r'C:\Users\Bikes\Desktop\Results.xlsx' , filetypes=(('Excel File', '.xlsx'),('All Files','*.*')) )               
                                                                                                                                                                                           
#save file with dialog.                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                           
win = Tk()                                                                                                                                                                                 
win.withdraw()                                                                                                                                                                             
#fileopen = filedialog.Open = "Results.xlsx"                                                                                                                                               
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Results.xlsx', initialdir='/', title = 'Save File', filetypes=(('Excel File', '.xlsx'),('Text File','.txt'),('All Files','*.*')))
```